# Is there an official documentation for Google search operators?

Tags: google-search

I can't find any official comprehensive documentation on Google search operators, just third-parties listing some of them. Am i a crapy searcher or there is indeed no such documentation? Why would be so?

Answer (score 0):

This basically tells you and lets you use a GUI to do it.

http://www.google.com/advanced_search

Here is a reference sheet:

https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en

I personally don't think this is the right stack exchange for the answer but since you are new I'll post it.

Comment: I already know that sites, the problem is they are not comprehensive, for example the following operators are missing : intitle, inurl . I'm looking for a comprehensive official list of search operators or for a reason of its nonexistence. I will ask in some of Google's help sites.

Oh, should i delete this post? what would have been the right stack to ask?

Answer (score 0):

Google Search Operator and Meaning

Pages containing keywords in:

- allinurl: / inurl:    – the URL
- allintitle: / intitle:    – the Title
- allintext: / intext:  – the text
- allinanchor:  /  inanchor:    – the anchor text
- filetype: – file types
- site: Narrow results to a site
- related:  Shows similar sites
- info: Shows page info
- define    Gives a definition
- The quotes (“”)   Search for a phrase
- The minus (-) Exclusion
- OR    Alternatives
- Numrange (..) – no longer works   Search for a range of numbers
- Asterisk (*)  Stands for a word or a few words
- AROUND (n)    Proximity search
- before:, after: date search

Comment: This should have been an edit to [your earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60725065/466862). Also, please make sure to format answers so they are readable.